# R: Reference Class Field Assignment - numeric and NA

Tags: r, reference-class

When assigning class types to fields in Reference Classes, what is the specification for numeric that allows for NAs?  For example, if I use the following code and try to assign a value of NA to the field extinctTime, I receive an error stating:

Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘extinctTime’, should be from class “numeric” or a subclass (was class “logical”)

I know there is likely a simple solution to permit the inclusion of NA extinction times for field extinctTime, but any advice would be great.

```
simClass <- setRefClass(
  Class = 'simClass',
  fields = list(
    ...
    extinct = 'logical',
    extinctTime = 'numeric'
    ... 
  )
)
```

Comment: Maybe assign `NA_real_` not `NA` (which is of class logical). A more general solution would be `as(NA,class(your_thing))`

Comment: @Frank, yeah...I was hoping something along these lines would work in reference classes, but it errors out and says: class “NA_real_” for field ‘extinctTime’ is not defined.  I've tried a few iterations of this without any success.

Comment: Ahhh, nevermind @Frank, I see what you're saying and it appears to have worked!  I was looking at the problem from the wrong perspective!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Np, good luck with your project!